# SQL phone number data correcting xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: sql, select, substring

I have a sql query to extract phone number from a Blackberry Enterprise Server to an asset type of sql database.  That problem I am running into is that the BES does not standardize the phone numbers, sometimes there is the log distance dial code of 1, very random.  But in the asset database I need the standard `xxx-xxx-xxxx` format.  Here is my select statement for that phone number line. This limits the Phone number to the 10 characters, but I also need to push a dash as `xxx-xxx-`xxxx

```
SELECT RIGHT([PhoneNumber], 10) AS PhoneNumber.
```

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Try using a different alias name.

Comment: What do you mean you need to "push a dash as xxx-xxx-xxxx"?  Some samples of problematic output might be helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't bother formatting the phone number in the database. That's a display issue that should be handled on the client side or in the rendering script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dashes are consistent in the source then you could just take `RIGHT(PhoneNumber,12)`:

If not, you should remove dashes, take the right 10, then add dashes back in:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),1,3)+'-'
      +SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),4,3)+'-'
      +SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),7,4)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/98d06/2/0)

Syntax may vary by database.

Comment: I think he's asking how to put in dashes, not take them out. Hard to tell though.

Comment: Thank you, this was perfect:   SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),1,3)+'-'
      +SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),4,3)+'-'
      +SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLACE(PhoneNumber,'-',''),10),7,4)